# Operadores booleanos Python

Tags: python, booleano

Hola mi pregunta es una duda muy sencilla, tengo estas dos expresiones y permítanme que las analice para ver si lo hago de forma correcta:

```
False or not (True and True)
False
```

En esta primera expresión siguiendo el orden recomendado, primero analizo not y tengo que compararlo con el resultado de los dos operadores entre paréntesis True and True que sería True, por tanto not True es False, y por último lo comparo con or, sería False or False es False.

La duda es en esta:

```
not not True or False and not True
False
```

Analizo not not True, not True es False, not False es True, not True es False, True and False es False y False or False es False.

La duda es por qué la segunda en la consola de Python me da True.
Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu razonamiento lógico es correcto y aplicas bien el orden, tu error me parece que es que simplemente te has liado entre tanto True y False:

Tu dices lo siguente:

> Analizo not not True, not True es False, not False es True, not True
>   es False, True and False es False y False or False es False.

Veamos,

> not not True, not True es False, not False es **True**...

Correcto, por lo tanto lo que hay antes del or es un **True**.

> not True es False, True and False es **False**..

Aqui hay un error, not True es False , pero lo que hay antes de and es un False por lo que es False and False, por lo que lo que hay después del or es **False**

> y **False** or False es False.

Aquí esta el error, antes del or hay un True como tu mismo indicas.

Paso a paso sería asi:
Como sabes los operadores logicos tienen un orden de prioridad:

```
1º not
2º and
3º or
```

Tu sentencia es:

```
not not True or False and not True
```

Primero tenemos que resolver las negaciones:

```
not not True or False and not True
not False or False and not True >> Dado que not True = False
True or False and not True >> Dado que not False = True
True or False and False >> Dado que not True = False
```

Ahora evaluamos los and:

```
True or False and False 
True or False >> Dado que False and False = False
```

Por último evaluamos el or:

```
True or False
True
```

Comment: Sí correcto. Explico como la analicé, aunque se puede deducir solo es por aclarar un poco más donde ha estado mi error. Primero miré not not True y me dio True, ahora me fui al final a not True que es False (había acabado con los not), descarté por ahora el "or False" y cogí comparé el True de not not True del principio con el False del final de not True, por tanto quedo True and False es False y seguidamente me fui al "or False" y lo comparé con el or, con el último False que he mencionado y me dio False

Comment: claro el error ha sido como tu has puesto no mirar el "False and" y coger el or False. El or ahí en ese lugar es solo para comparar las dos expresiones

Comment: Vale @Vicente ahora entiendo de donde sale el True and False. El error entonces estaba en que saltaste por encima del or' en busca del dato. Básicamente los operadores boleanos se comportan igual que los aritméticos, siempre evalúan los datos que tienen inmediatamente a ambos lados, si tenemos 2+4*5 el * se evalúa antes que + pero coge los dados a sus lados (4*5), en tu caso es como si hicieras 5*2+4 lo que es incorrecto. Realmente tu has evaluado la expresión: not not True and not True or False

Comment: Sí es el orden de evaluación creo que se llama, es que estoy empezando con esto de Python :)

Comment: Pues ánimo a mi personalmente me encanta Python, cualquier duda por aquí estamos :)

Answer (score 2):

La expresión `not not True or False and not True` da `True`, simplemente porque tienes un **`or`**.

**`or`**, denota que solo una de las dos expresiones principales necesita ser verdadera. Dicho esto, Python ejecutará la primera expresión `not not True`, luego como este resulta en `True`, python ya no revisará la expression siguiente; `False and not True`. Así que el resultado final es `True`, sin importar que las otras partes sean `False`.

El orden de razonamiento seria así:

```
not not True or False and not True
              ↓
not False or False and not True
              ↓
# Python encuentra que la primera expresion
# ya es True, así que deja de ejecutar sigue
# despues del operador or.
True or False and not True
              ↓
True
```

Mas arriba hablo de expresión principal, porque básicamente el código original equivale a:

```
>>> (not not True) or (False and not True)
```

Donde podemos ver que hay dos grupos separador por **`or`**. Luego en el segundo grupo hay dos sub grupos `(False)` y `(not True)`.

```
>>> (not not True) or ((False) and (not True))
```

Todas estas expresiones son iguales, y deben devolver `True`.

Comment: Las dos respuestas me han resuelto la duda, como bien indicas en la tuya lo ideal es usar paréntesis para separar las distintas expresiones y tenerlo más claro.

Answer (score 1):

Es por la prioridad operacional de Python que sigue el siguiente orden:

1ro  **not**  (Negacion)
2do  **and**  (Conjuncion)
3er  **or**   (disyuncion)

Comment: De acuerdo pero según eso como analizarías la segunda expresión porque a mí como se ve en la pregunta me da False, y sin embargo Python da True, esa sería mi duda.

Comment: de la siguiente manera:                                                                      not (not (True)) or( False and not (True))

Comment: Sí de esa manera en la que la has remarcado se ve también muy claro, es conveniente hacerlo así, al final da True ya que como comenté arriba or lo que hace es comparar las dos expresiones y no está añadido al valor False como yo creía